# Is there any issue with a valid Qatar visa if I have an old passport number?

Tags: visas, qatar

Is there any issue with a valid Qatar visa with an old passport number to travel from Qatar to India with a new passport?

Comment: Do you still possess the old passport itself?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can bring them both together, this is not a problem at all. Especially if your new passport has the number of your old passport somewhere.

Comment: Why/how would the new passport have the old passport's number?  As far as I'm aware this is not a thing.

Comment: The passport itself has a different number, but it could have a note, something like this: "passport issued in replacement of passport number xyz".

Comment: @André I have never seen a passport with such a note added by the passport issuer. Have you?

Comment: Yes, and the old passport has a valid visa on it. The visa is still in use and was accepted several times. Of course, since the old passport expired it has only been used together with a valid one.